# "There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later"

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, upgrade

We have upgraded Magento version 1.7 to 1.9.1.1 but when I click on "place order" button, this error shows **"There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later"**, while choosing cash on delivery payment option.

We have enabled log file and this shows this error:

> 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_PaypalUk_Block_Link_Shortcut' in /data/flavorwest_magikcommerce/app/Mage.php

We do not use the default theme, but we have tested it on the RWD default theme but same error shows

Comment: please enable log and check in log file

Comment: Yes we have enable log file shows this error Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_PaypalUk_Block_Link_Shortcut' in /data/flavorwest_magikcommerce/app/Mage.php

Comment: Did you upgrade your template overrides? Judging from the error you did not. Part of a Magento upgrade is identifying what changed in `base/default` and applying those changes to templates you have put in `mypackage/mytheme`.

Comment: We have test for rwd default theme but same error shows

Comment: Did you upgrade your database or migrate and upgrade? Have you re-entered your credentials for Paypal? Can you checkout with any other methods?